# PDF to bitmap to count area of black

Tags: python, pdf, pixel

Hi I'm looking for an easy way to convert a pdf to a bitmap so that I can count the propertion of black to white pixels. I'm thinking python maybe with PyPPDF2 or pdf2image and converting to jpg. But it would be nice to have the bitmap internally so that I don't have to reopen the jpg with some other module. I'm not sure. Any ideas are welcome?